# ¿"Para que" con valor condicional?

Tags: sintaxis

¿Es posible que en este contexto la conjunción final *para que* tenga valor condicional? (=  *Algo muy raro debe haber ocurrido si te presentas en mi casa*)

> (a) Debe haber ocurrido algo para que todos estén preocupados por él.
>
> (b) Algo muy raro debe haber ocurrido para que te presentes en mi
>   casa.

Comment: Sí, estás en lo cierto.

Comment: A ver si lo he entendido bien... Entonces estas oraciones deberían ser consideradas como oraciones condicionales y no finales, ¿verdad?

Comment: Digamos (a) significa:
Proposición 1:   "Todos están preocupados por él"
Proposición 2:   "Todos se preocuparían por él sí y sólo sí algo hubiese ocurrido." 
Entonces quien habla encuentra que Proposición 1 es verdadera. Es decir, es un hecho que todos están preocupados por él. Asume que Proposición 2 es verdadera y entonces concluye.
"Necesariamente algo sucedió, porque todos están preocupados por él".

Comment: Otra forma de decirlo, ahora para el caso (b)
"Te presentaste en mi casa. No te hubieses presentado si algo muy raro no hubiese pasado. Entonces, algo muy raro pasó."

Comment: @user1420303 tus comentarios son extremadamente valiosos. ¡Anímate a juntarlos en una respuesta para que se puedan leer mejor!

Comment: A mí me parece una deducción lógica

Comment: El `para qué` no forma oraciones condicionales. Forma subordinadas finales. No expone condición, sino causalidad. El grado de certeza de la causalidad, no la convierte en condicional.

Answer (score 2):

Si miramos las reglas gramaticales para la construcción de oraciones condicionales, encontraremos que el "para que" no cumple con ellas.

La oración condicional es del tipo **oración subordinada**. Es decir, *oración subordinada adverbial condicional*, pero no es la única en esta categoría.

*Algo ha tenido que pasar* no expone condición, exponse **causalidad**.

Esto nos lleva a otro tipo de oraciones subordinadas. La **oración subordinada adverbial  final**.

[Ejemplos](http://www.gramaticas.net/2012/06/ejemplos-de-subordinadas-adverbiales_2398.html?m=1)

En respuesta al comentario de @user1420...

> Otra forma de decirlo, ahora para el caso (b) "Te presentaste en mi
>   casa. No te hubieses presentado si algo muy raro no hubiese pasado.
>   Entonces, algo muy raro pasó."

Este argumento es falaz, y en el mejor de los casos, demuestra que es una oración subordinada final

> Te presentaste en mi casa [...] Entonces, algo muy raro pasó.

**Causa - efecto**

La oración

> No te hubieses presentado si algo muy raro no hubiese pasado

Si es condicional, pero ha sido elidida en la frase original. Se sobreentiende esta condición. Por lo que, *estás en casa **porque** eso ha pasado*

Otra vez... **Causa-efecto**